# How do you call these three different kinds of air source heat pump?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump

What is the name of each of these three **formats** (or **form factor**) of air source heat pump outdoor units?

1. LG LMU300HHV - Variable speed, 4 zones, 30 kBtu, 20 SEER

[image: LG LMU300HHV]

2. LG LMU480HV - Variable speed, multiple zones via branch box, 48 kBtu, 19.5 SEER

[image: LG LMU480HV]

3. Trane XV18 - Variable speed, multiple zones via branch box, ?? kBtu, 18 SEER

[image: Trane XV18]

### Common denominator

Tried to get models that are relatively close in terms of functionality. It's understandable that larger models can have more capabilities but I'm posting this to try to factor this out, and get the name of the **form factor**.

### Ducted vs ductless

Some manufacturers label their heat pump as ductless but how do they know if I'm using ducts or not? Or is a ductless heat pump referring to the usage of refrigerant line-sets to indoor fan coils? Isn't that 100% of all the heat pumps though? There doesn't seem to be a type of heat pump that directly cools or warms the air then pushes that air straight into ducts in the home. So it can be concluded that ducted vs ductless refers to the overall system, **and has nothing to do with the form-factor of the outdoor unit**.

### "X-split"

Seems like some people tend to apply the word 'mini-split' to the first one but from my research mini-split just refers to the fact that each indoor unit services a single room instead of the whole home. Seems to be a catch-all that covers both 'single-split' (1 outdoor unit, 1 head) and 'multi-split' (1 outdoor unit, 2 or more heads) as long as the rooms being serviced are separate. So again, words like 'mini-split', 'multi-split', and 'single-split' refers to the overall system, **and has nothing to do with the form-factor of the outdoor unit**.

### Inverter vs something that's not an inverter?

I was tempted to name the first two "inverters" and the Trane model an "older non-inverter" but according to [this site](https://getpureair.com/heat-pump-inverter-tech/) the old Trane form factor is also an inverter.

### Asian-style heat pump?

One potential candidate in the factor of the naming is that the first two styles I posted above from LG appear to be very common among Asian-Pacific brands such as Daikin, Mitsubishi, LG, Samsung, Fujitsu, etc. That is not to say that North-American manufacturers don't also have this form-factor (Trane has the XV19 in this form-factor) but they don't seem as common.

## Reiterating the question:

How do you name these three different forms of heat pumps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t a formally defined naming scheme that is consistent throughout the industry.

That having been said, the entire system would be called “ductless mini-split”. It has multiple components: an outdoor inverter compressor heat-pump, the refrigerant line sets, the indoor head units.

You’re correct that you could hook up one of those outdoor inverter compressor heat pumps to a line set that actually connected to a ducted air-handler with coil inside the home.  In that case, you wouldn’t have a ductless mini-split system. You would have a forced-air heat pump system.

There are also other kinds of heat pumps. The most common ones that people associate with ductless mini-splits are called air-to-air, they also make air to water, water to air, and even water to water heat pumps.

A “heat pump” works like a refrigerator, except the inside of the “fridge” is your whole house. It acts as an A/C like a fridge cools its contents. If you run the refrigerant lines in reverse, it heats your house just like the fridge generates heat on the back and sides as it cools.

That Trane unit seems to only operate in cooling mode. It might also be a single zone system — which really just means only connectors for a single line set — which would mean it’s meant to be used with an air handler and coil inside the home. But it’s really fundamentally the same in terms of the physics of the LG heat pumps that you would normally use with a mini-split system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do you call those three different form-factors of the outdoor inverter unit?

Comment: @Daniel why is the name of the form factor important to you? Is this for a school test?

Comment: the answer is important to me because: 1. it allows me to search for the type of form-factor I want, 2. I can specify to the contractor the limitations of the heat pump form-factor

Comment: @Daniel perhaps something along the combination of  `AC outdoor unit`, `vertical fan`, `horizontal fan`, `dual fan`

Comment: I don’t think there’s a formal naming scheme in fact. I think you should start with the limitations that you have and the desired overall system type (ducted vs ductless, etc) and then find the right model based on that. I think it’s a sign that you need the help of a professional HVAC installer if you are starting with form factor. Start with your heating and cooling needs and work backward from that.

Comment: I beg to differ @RibaldEddie. Some people such as myself, may at times factor in the aesthetics of a product when making a purchase. In my specific example, and this doesn't matter for the actual question at hand, I don't want the big and bulky form-factor, I'm only looking at the slimmer vertical-fan types. Regardless, I don't know why you're constantly trying to deviate from the question, whether asking if it's for a school test or searching for a product, how does that change the answer??

Comment: Your comment "I don’t think there’s a formal naming scheme in fact." is the closest thing to the best answer I've received so far. It does look like this is the case. This is surprising to me because if you look at electrical component packaging, there are so many specific names such as QFN, BGA, etc.

Comment: I've also updated my question based on your responses to make the question more clear.
If you change your answer to the comment you made "there is no formal naming scheme" I'm ready to mark that as the accepted answer

Comment: @Daniel If you browse questions here, you'll often find people making recommendations in answers that go against the OP's wishes simply because the way the OP wants to do things isn't a good idea. In your case (maybe you've already done this and haven't shared it), you'd want to determine your HVAC loads and needs, _then_ find condenser units that meet those needs. From among those that meet your needs, chose the one that fits your budget, space and aesthetic constraints. You _appear_ to be starting with the aesthetic constraints which may well leave you unhappy in the long run.

Comment: Hi @Freeman, I understand the need to ask one's self "what is this person REALLY asking?" but in this case I am just really asking a pure and simple uncomplicated question for the sake of curiosity and understanding. Not that it's any of your business but I am doing my due diligence, getting multiple quotes, getting a professional energy evaluation done on my current setup (and there will be a post-test as well), and currently holding a bachelor's in Mechanical Engineering where I studied HVAC systems. So I'm just looking for an answer to my question, not the this attitude.

Comment: This "attitude" lead to some background info that helps people better frame an answer for you, so I guess it was worthwhile. Sometimes it's hard to know what someone is really after (even though your question is comprehensive and well formatted), and some prompting questions in the comments finally get us to the point where when know that so an appropriate answer can be provided.

Comment: TBH, your best bet may be to simply show your HVAC contractor(s) pics of the style you're after and have them give you options. As noted, there probably isn't a formal naming scheme, so it gets down to "point and grunt". ;)

Comment: @FreeMan hahaha yeah it sounds like that is the best way. There's no need for me to do that though because I'm really only going for the Japanese brands which only have the first two form factors for residential use.
But that's the heart of the back-and-forth with RibaldEddie, if he changes his answer to something like "there probably isn't a formal naming scheme"  I would mark this answer as the accepted one. Instead it looks like he downvoted my question. (it was at +1 but after my response it was downvoted)

Comment: I didn’t downvote your question.

Comment: Ah strange, the timing made it look like you did. Regardless thanks for updating your answer. I've marked it as the accepted one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The big train style unit is an older style (prior to inverters)

The Flat style are usually mini split or ductless but not always the newer replacements of high efficiency ducted systems with only a single zone may look just like this but boast efficiencies +18 up to 23 where the old systems big square were common as a 13 for the seasonal efficienc(higher is better)

Comment: The high end right now is 38 SEER, but that may require the "mini-split" form factor.

Comment: Yes high efficiency condenser coils and inverter/ vfd compressor control are the main differences, inside the mini splits have no ductwork to heat and cool it all goes into the home less a tiny loss on the line set. I am not sure if the latest and greatest efficiency ever pays back , today the high efficiency central air is upper teens to mid 20’s. Todays less expensive units run 15-18 seer, 10-15 years ago they were top of the line. So the efficiency gains end up reducing the cost over the years, mini splits run higher seer and now have efficient heating without heat strips down to -5F &lower